# update on "merModLmerTest" object returns object of class "lmerMod"

Tags: r, regression

Just wondering whether this is well-known / desirable behaviour... ?

Reproducible example:

```
## import lmerTest package
library(lmerTest)

## an object of class merModLmerTest
m <- lmer(Informed.liking ~ Gender+Information+Product +(1|Consumer), data=ham)

class(m)
class(update(m,REML=FALSE))
```

Comment: Questions about how to code in R are off topic here. This should be on topic on Stack Overflow, so if you wait, we will try to migrate it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious to me at least. You can work around it with `as(.,"merModLmerTest")` ...

```
library(lmerTest)
m <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
m2 <- update(m,REML=FALSE)
m3 <- as(m2,"merModLmerTest")
class(m3)  ## "merModLmerTest"
```

Or you can use this helper function:

```
update2 <- function(x,...) {
   z <- update(x,...)
   return(as(z,"merModLmerTest"))
}
update2(m,REML=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful!